# How do I migrate the basic page content to another site?

Tags: 7, backups

I have nearly 250  basic pages content and I want to migrate the same content to another Drupal website. I tried using the [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)  module, but it doesn't work well. How can I do this?

Comment: @kiamlaluno question that short & simple, with no context, cannot possibly have an answer that takes context into account and is not short & simple, can it?

Comment: The note is referring to the answer's context, not the question's context. A short question doesn't necessarily need a short answer, especially if the answers are similar to "try this module" and don't give any information about why that module is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the **[Migrate Module](https://drupal.org/project/migrate)** for this.

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly recommended).

For more details about the module you could go through the README.txt of this module.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand from your short question, you want to export only some content to another Drupal installation. In this case Backup and Migrate module will not do any good for you, because it is mainly designed for backing up migrating at database level.

[Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) will allow you to export and import nodes to another Drupal installation.

> Using this module you can save yourself a lot of time setting up new
>   websites that have similar nodes to websites you've already made,
>   migrating nodes to new Drupal versions, or between
>   development/staging/production sites.